# WooCommerce: Run some code only once on order status change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I would like to trigger an action hook (or something similar) on specific order status change. The code should be run only once from order status "processing" to "completed".

Here is m code attempt:

```
   function payment_complete( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){
            if( $new_status == "completed" && $old_status == "processing") {
               // $this->generate_order_file($order_id); 
               echo '<script>alert("Working now, but not once:()")</script>'; 
            }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'payment_complete', 99, 3 );
```

But it seems that my code runs multiple times. I am stuck for instance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to make the order status change from "processing" to "complete" to be triggered only once for your code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed', 'order_processing_to_completed', 100, 2 );
function order_processing_to_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Avoid hook to be triggered multiple times at once
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed' ) > 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check that this action hook has not been triggered before
    if ( ! $order->get_meta( '_processing_to_completed' ) ) {
        // Grab the action in WordPress error logs (for testing)
        error_log('"processing_to_completed" Run once only.');
        
        // Add a custom meta data to flag the action as triggered
        $order->update_meta_data( '_processing_to_completed', 'yes' );
        $order->save(); // Save

        // Here add your code to be run once
    }
}
```

**Note:** You should not use `payment_complete` function name as it could be used by another plugin.

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**The code inside the if statement will get triggered only once.**

Comment: Thank you so much @LoicTheAztec.
I learn so much from you!

Comment: One more question.
Thank you in advance!
Where usually in DB is stored "_processing_to_completed" meta field?

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов in `wp_postmeta` table as all order meta data

Comment: Thanks! I will find it.

Comment: Hello, Can i use this action like
woocommerce_order_status_{old_status}_to_{new_status}?

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов yes ?

Comment: I want to ask you can I use this action - woocommerce_order_status_{old_status}_to_{new_status} for example processing to cancelled or other? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов Yes of course… `old_status` is the old status and  `new_status ` is the current order status (the new one). For example for orders that change from `processing` to `cancelled` status use `woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_cancelled`

Comment: Thank you! One laat question, did you test this for custom order status?

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов All related composite hooks works also for custom order statuses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229986/discussion-between---and-loictheaztec).

Comment: Hi, how can I use this function when bulk changing the order status from processing to completed for each order?